# The element attribute _ngcontent key refresh everytime

Tags: angular

The element attribute _ngcontent key refresh everytime。

eg. _ngcontent-`mrv`-c182 _ngcontent-`llb`-c182. The word `mrv` is dynamic，it change everytime load。

I want to use a statistic _ngcontent key, so that I can generate **sha256-key** for CSP scene。

Is there a configuration to survive static values。

Answer (score 0):

It is `AppId`.

Token

```
export const APP_ID = new InjectionToken<string>('AppId');
```

Default provide

```
export function _appIdRandomProviderFactory() {
  return `${_randomChar()}${_randomChar()}${_randomChar()}`;
}
```